# Tkinter: Merging 2 windows

Tags: python, tkinter

I've been playing around with my first Python Tkinter GUI.
Below you van find te script I've made. Must be honest, I've looked around on the internet to find out how to do it.

When I run my script now I get 2 seperate windows.
One window, lets call this "window A", with my text and input boxes and one empty window, lets call this "window B".

When I click on "Run" in "window A" my phyton script(tennisMatchProbability.py in this case) is triggered and the results of that script (tennisMatchProbability.py) are displayed in "window B".

This is the output that "tennisMatchProbability.py" gives.

```
Server Game = 0.735729230769
Receiver Game= 0.264270769231
Tiebreak = 0.337026817252
Server Set = 0.205146215901
Receiver Set= 0.794853784099
Match Server= 0.108987765053
Match Receiver= 0.891012234947
```

What I would like to achieve is that both windows are merged into one window.

I've been trying everything that I could think of but can't figure it out.

```
from Tkinter import *
import sys
sys.path.append("C:\Users\Magali\Desktop\Tennis\tennisMatchProbability.py")

class App(Frame):
    def run_script(self):
        sys.stdout = self
        try:
            del(sys.modules["tennisMatchProbability"])
        except:
            ## Yeah, it's a real ugly solution...
            pass
        import tennisMatchProbability
        tennisMatchProbability.matchProb()
        sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__


    def build_widgets(self):
        self.text1 = Text(self)
        self.text1.pack(side=TOP)


        master = Tk()
        Label(master, text="First Name").grid(row=0)
        Label(master, text="Last Name").grid(row=1)
        Label(master, text="Game Score").grid(row=2)
        Label(master, text="Set Score").grid(row=3)

        e1 = Entry(master)
        e2 = Entry(master)
        e3 = Entry(master)
        e4 = Entry(master)
        e1.delete(0,END)
        e2.delete(0,END)
        e3.delete(0,END)
        e4.delete(0,END)


        e1.insert(10,"Novak")
        e2.insert(10,"Djokovic")
        e3.insert(10,"30-15")
        e4.insert(10,"3-1")


        e1.grid(row=0, column=1)
        e2.grid(row=1, column=1)
        e3.grid(row=2, column=1)
        e4.grid(row=3, column=1)

        Button(master, text='Run', command=self.run_script).grid(row=4, column=1, sticky=W, pady=4)



    def write(self, txt):
        self.text1.insert(INSERT, txt)

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack()
        self.build_widgets()


root = Tk()
app = App(master = root)
app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is easy:
In the build_widgets method you are constructing a new Tk frame and tcl interpreter with

```
        master = Tk()
```

You should never have two Tk() calls in your application.
The solution is to delete this line and change every occurance of master to self. Self represent your app class, which inherits from the tk.Frame class and is therefore your main frame.

Also your construction of run_scipt is rather weird. Why don't you do it like this?

```
    def run_script(self):
        inputs = self.read_tk_fields()
        result = tennisMatchProbability.matchProb(inputs)
```

Here is the full code

```
from Tkinter import *
import sys
sys.path.append("C:\Users\Magali\Desktop\Tennis\tennisMatchProbability.py")
import tennisMatchProbability

class App(Frame):

    def run_script(self):
        inputs = self.read_tk_field()
        result = tennisMatchProbability.matchProb(inputs)
        self.show_prob_result(result)

    def show_prob_result(self,result):
        self.result_label.config(text=result)

    def build_widgets(self):

        Label(self, text="First Name").grid(row=0)
        Label(self, text="Last Name").grid(row=1)
        Label(self, text="Game Score").grid(row=2)
        Label(self, text="Set Score").grid(row=3)

        e1 = Entry(self)
        e2 = Entry(self)
        e3 = Entry(self)
        e4 = Entry(self)
        self.result_label = Label(self)

        e1.insert(10,"Novak")
        e2.insert(10,"Djokovic")
        e3.insert(10,"30-15")
        e4.insert(10,"3-1")

        e1.grid(row=0, column=1)
        e2.grid(row=1, column=1)
        e3.grid(row=2, column=1)
        e4.grid(row=3, column=1)
        self.result_label.grid(row=4, column=1)

        Button(self, text='Run', command=self.run_script).grid(row=5, column=1, sticky=W, pady=4)

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack()
        self.build_widgets()


root = Tk()
app = App(master = root)
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: I've removed "master = Tk() and changed all "master" enteries to "self". But when I run it now "CMD" is "hanging"....

Comment: You also have to remove the self.text1 part or change pack to grid. Also you should not change the master entries in __init__

Answer (score 0):

@Jannick, with your script I don't get the results in the GUI. With your script I get the results in CMD and the "Run" bottun gives an error

With my code below I get the results in the GUI.

```
from Tkinter import *
import sys
sys.path.append("C:\Users\Magali\Desktop\Tennis\tennisMatchProbability.py")

class App(Frame):
    def run_script(self):
        sys.stdout = self
        try:
            del(sys.modules["tennisMatchProbability"])
        except:
            ## Yeah, it's a real ugly solution...
            pass
        import tennisMatchProbability
        tennisMatchProbability.matchProb()
        sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__


    def build_widgets(self):
        self.text1 = Text(self)
        self.text1.grid(row=5)



        Label(self, text="First Name").grid(row=0)
        Label(self, text="Last Name").grid(row=1)
        Label(self, text="Game Score").grid(row=2)
        Label(self, text="Set Score").grid(row=3)

        e1 = Entry(self)
        e2 = Entry(self)
        e3 = Entry(self)
        e4 = Entry(self)
        e1.delete(0,END)
        e2.delete(0,END)
        e3.delete(0,END)
        e4.delete(0,END)


        e1.insert(10,"Novak")
        e2.insert(10,"Djokovic")
        e3.insert(10,"30-15")
        e4.insert(10,"3-1")


        e1.grid(row=0,column=1)
        e2.grid(row=1, column=1)
        e3.grid(row=2, column=1)
        e4.grid(row=3, column=1)

        Button(self,text='Run', command=self.run_script).grid(row=4, column=1, sticky=W, pady=4)



    def write(self, txt):
        self.text1.insert(INSERT, txt)

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack()
        self.build_widgets()


root = Tk()
app = App(master = root)
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: I wanted to indicate that you should instead of using stdout and printing, which is a pretty bad solution pass the results you are generating in tennisMatchProbability as a function return argument. You can use result then to change your gui accordingly. So in my code after reslt = ... you should use result to change the GUI as you want.

Comment: @Jannick, so how would your code than look like? Would you mind adjusting it in your answer? thanks

Comment: I added some stuff but as I don't know what your tennis thing returns and I don't know what you want this is only a guide.

Comment: @Jannick, see question field for the output of the tennisMatchProbability.py. When I run your script I still get the tennisMatchProbability in command prompt and not in the GUI likt in my script.

Comment: You should change your tennisMatchProbability script to return these value as a function return instead of printing them.

Comment: One last thing, i've change the print to return, but now I get the error....Attribute error: App instance has no attribute 'read_tk_field"

Comment: Because I just made it up for you to write. If your tennis thing doesn't need inputs just delete it.